# what is this brown patch on ivy leaves,

Tags: english-ivy

please see what is this brown patch on my ivy leaf. This has turned from yellowing into dark brown. tips are dying and getting lazy to grow.[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential causes for this, but it’s hard to tell without knowing where you are growing the ivy (I’m guessing from the picture it’s an outdoor plant?). I don’t know how often you water the ivy, but it may be that it’s an over watering issue or some form of environmental stress (did your area have a heat wave or a cold wave?). I’d also check the pot to see if it’s too small for the ivy. My ivy’s leaves turned yellow once when I failed to repot it into a bigger pot.